# Flask JavaScript/HTML Scripts Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a flask web application I am creating( also using Angular CLI), and I have a button. I am trying to use JavaScript to conduct an action on the button click but for whatever reason I can't get the JavaScript to work.

However when I copy the java Script into a completely different simple flask project (that I downloaded from online), it works fine?

Does anyone know if I have to do something in my flask project to get the javascript working?

I read somewhere it has to do with the way i run the flask app ? (0.0.0.0 vs localhost) but im not sure

Here's the code I am trying to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The onclick Event</h1>

<p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on.</p>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors would be helpful. Personally I don’t like the inline use of functions could you maybe try that and add a console.log()

Comment: The error was unable to find referene to myFunction, it occurs with any code that requires javascript

Answer (score 0):

You passed function result as an argument instead of function instead.
Use

```
onclick="myFunction"
```

But if you want do it in a professional way you should do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The onclick Event</h1>

<p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on.</p>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button>Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction)
function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And using innerHTML to inserting data isn't the best option too. In javascript you can create DOM elementr programaticaly.

Comment: Have you opened dev tools and checked if script actually exists?

Comment: I dont think the script is being recognized/exists? Would you happen to know how I can fix that? I've been trying to fix this for hours :(

Comment: Briefly looking at the docs, do you have any css? in a separate file.. is that loading? If so--or not try it that way using url_for('static', filename='script.js')

Comment: No I am not currently using any css, however I do have a css file where I can add css if needed. This is how my python project currently is:

Project->
-Angular Server
-Flask Server

I run the flask server (which is all the backend stuff) and angular server (which is all the HTML/CSS/JS stuff). None of the JS stuff seems to be working. I am also accessing the website through angular's server not flask

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Not sure why you would be using js like that in angular then. Do you still use the cli to generate components? That’s where your js should be

Comment: Right now I am not because if I run the Angular server all my updates occur immediately, I tried building with cli into a static folder but it didnt make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if none of the console.log's show up then its a issue with how it's compiled

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
console.log('loaded)
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
function myFunction(e) {
console.log(e);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}

})
```

Comment: Yea nothing prints out

Answer (score 0):

Try from a ‘static’ folder in the root directory. Literally call it static and then place a js file inside.
Then in the html try this

Comment: I tried adding a static folder and template folder and it still didn't work. Thanks for taking your time to help me btw!